# Unable to open Netcdf variable in xarray

Tags: python, netcdf, python-xarray

I am opening a dataset using xarray with this line: `DS = xr.open_dataset(dataDIR)`. When I use `DS.variables`, I see that there's a variable named 'u-vel', however, when I try to open this variable using `DS.u-vel`, it returns me the following:

> 'Dataset' object has no attribute 'u'

I think that the python is interpreting it as me trying to open the u variable in DS and subtract it from my local variable vel. I have tried using `DS."u-vel"`, but it did not work either.

Does anybody know how should I open this variable using xarray?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`u-vel` is not a valid name for a Python attribute. You'll want to use the getitem interface to the dataset to access this variable:

```py
da = ds['u-vel']
```

In general, while the attribute style access is convenient, I think its better to default to using the getitem access pattern to avoid issues like this one as well as conflicts with other parts of the xarray namespace.

Comment: I completely forgot about the getitem, thought it wouldn't work in xarray, but it did, thanks!